# TensorFlow image classification model gives different prediction when run in Spyder IDE and in CMD

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-classification

I have made a TensorFlow model script that saves the model for later use.
Its a Image classification model with sequential neural network that takes in the image and classifies it based on three output classes.

When I run the model on the same file in Spyder IDE and with command prompt, I get significantly different results for prediction from each, even when using the same virtual environment.

The resulted predictions for the three classes might be like:
Spyder IDE prediction:
Class1 = 0.17  - Class2 = 0.05  - Class3 = 0.78

running the script in CMD prediction:
Class1 = 0.03  - Class2 = 0.01  - Class3 = 0.96

Many thanks in advance if anyone knows why is this so. I am looking to learn here.

I don't think I am using dropout or anything that type to cause this sort of randomness.
I use the same virtual environment for both cases so the TF version should be the same.

My scrip that creates the model:

```
training_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir, 
                                            validation_split=0.2,
                                            subset="training",
                                            batch_size=32, 
                                            image_size=(img_size,img_size),
                                            seed=50)

validation_data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(data_dir, 
                                            validation_split=0.2,
                                            subset="validation",
                                            batch_size=32, 
                                            image_size=(img_size,img_size),
                                            seed=50)

# Get class names
class_names = training_data.class_names
print(class_names)

# Normalize pixel values between 0 & 1
# Each pixel is currently values between 0 & 255 for RGB colors
# Neural networks work best with normalized data
# Divide all values by the max value 255
norm_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1/255.)

# Apply the division to all data in traing data set
training_data_norm = training_data.map(lambda x, y: (norm_layer(x), y))

# Do same for test (validation) dataset
validation_data_norm = validation_data.map(lambda x, y: (norm_layer(x), y))

# Check for normalization
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(training_data_norm))
image_batch[0]

model_4 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  Conv2D(filters=10, 
          kernel_size=3, # Or (3, 3)
          activation="relu", 
          # Input shape (height, width, colour channels)
          input_shape=(img_size, img_size, 3)), 
  MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, # Or (2, 2)
            padding="valid"), # Or 'same'
  Conv2D(10, 3, activation="relu"), # Filters, Kernel Size, activation
  MaxPool2D(), 
  Conv2D(10, 3, activation="relu"),
  MaxPool2D(),
  Flatten(),
  Dense(3, activation="softmax") # Binary activation output layer
])

# Compile the model
model_4.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=["accuracy"])

# Fit the model
history_4 = model_4.fit(training_data_norm,
                        epochs=epochs_tf
                        ,
                        # Step through 50 batches of 32
                        steps_per_epoch=len(training_data_norm), 
                        # Validate while fitting
                        validation_data=validation_data_norm, 
                        # Step through in batches of 32
                        validation_steps=len(validation_data_norm))

# Plot models training curves
pd.DataFrame(history_4.history).plot(figsize=(20, 10))

model_4.save(r"C:\nn")
```

And this is how I run the model:

```
my_image = tf.io.read_file(path)
my_image = tf.image.decode_image(my_image) # Turn file into a tensor
my_image = tf.image.resize(my_image, size=[model_dpi, model_dpi]) # Resize image
my_image = my_image / 255 # Normalize data
model.predict(tf.expand_dims(my_image, axis=0), verbose = 0
```

I checked that it is 100% sure that they are running the same file in both systems.
I made sure that they both run in the same virtual environment.
Since I use the same virtual environment I am sure that the TF versions are both same when I run the scripts.

Comment: When you run your model from Spyder or CMD do you train your model every time (e.g. train your model, save it to disk, load, inference)? Or you've trained your model once and now reading it from disk and performing inference?

Comment: I save the model with model.save. And load it from a the disc from different laptops on different interface.

Comment: Could it be the image I insert tot he model during the validation test? I used 
tf.image.resize for that image. And is it possible that it changes the image in different ways on different interfaces? So basically it is validating a different image?

Comment: When you resize the image, you invoke some interpolation function and I doubt that TF on different platforms uses different interpolation functions. 
You should try saving your model, your inference data after pre-processing (after resizing, normalization, etc) and running the exact same data through the exact same model

Answer (score 0):

I think that it could be due to the conv2d initializer

By default the kernels initialization is done with `tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform`

try to set the seed to a fixed one

```
tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(
    seed=42
)
```

Note that, as stated by keras:

> seed  A Python integer. Used to make the behavior of the initializer
> deterministic. Note that a seeded initializer will not produce the
> same random values across multiple calls, but multiple initializers
> will produce the same sequence when constructed with the same seed
> value.

```
Conv2D(filters=10, 
          kernel_size=3, # Or (3, 3)
          activation="relu", 
          # Input shape (height, width, colour channels)
          input_shape=(img_size, img_size, 3),
          kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(
          seed=42
))
```